How can I print ASCII art in batch without it printing weird symbols?
So basically I am making a multitool, (don't judge me) and I want to print the following ASCII art, but when I do, some weird symbols come out instead of it. I know this has to do with the characters, but I don't know how to fix this.
░██████╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗░█████╗░░█████╗░██╗██╗░██████╗
██╔════╝██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██║╚█║██╔════╝
╚█████╗░██║░░╚═╝███████║██║░░██║██║░░██║██║░╚╝╚█████╗░
░╚═══██╗██║░░██╗██╔══██║██║░░██║██║░░██║██║░░░░╚═══██╗
██████╔╝╚█████╔╝██║░░██║╚█████╔╝╚█████╔╝██║░░░██████╔╝
╚═════╝░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚════╝░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░░╚═════╝░

███╗░░░███╗██╗░░░██╗██╗░░░░░████████╗██╗████████╗░█████╗░░█████╗░██╗░░░░░
████╗░████║██║░░░██║██║░░░░░╚══██╔══╝██║╚══██╔══╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██║░░░░░
██╔████╔██║██║░░░██║██║░░░░░░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║░░██║██║░░██║██║░░░░░
██║╚██╔╝██║██║░░░██║██║░░░░░░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║░░██║██║░░██║██║░░░░░
██║░╚═╝░██║╚██████╔╝███████╗░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║░░░╚█████╔╝╚█████╔╝███████╗
╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚══════╝░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░░╚════╝░░╚════╝░╚══════╝

https://i.sstatic.net/BH4dLqRz.png
I have tried many things, none worked. I have tried type, and many other solutions I found on stackoverflow.

Update: I tried:
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com') do for %%H in (%%G) do set /A "CodePage=%%H" 2>nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >nul
type logo.txt 
%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com %CodePage% >nul

It kind of works... it outputs what I want, but with some weird � characters:
░██████╗░█████╗░██╗░░██╗░█████╗░░█████╗░██╗██╗░██████╗
██╔════╝██╔══██╗██║░░██║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██║╚█║██╔════╝
╚█████╗░██║░░╚═╝███████║██║░░██║██║░░██║██║░╚╝╚█████╗░
░╚═══█��╗██║░░██╗██╔══██║██║░░██║██║░░██║██║░░░░╚═══██╗
██████╔╝╚█████╔╝██║░░██║╚█████╔╝╚█████╔╝██║░░░██████╔╝
╚═════╝░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝░╚════╝░░╚════╝░╚═╝░░░╚═════╝░

███╗░░░███╗█��╗░░░██╗██╗░░░░░████████╗██╗████████╗░█████╗░░█████╗░██╗░░░░░
████╗░████║██║░░░██║██║░░░░░╚══██╔══╝██║╚══██╔══╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██║░░░░░
██╔████╔██║██║░░░██║██║░░░░░░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║░░██║██║░░██║██║░░░░░
██║╚██╔╝██║██║░░░██║██║░░░░░░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║░░██║██║░░██║██║░░░░░
██║░╚═╝░██║╚██████╔╝███████╗░░░██║░░░██║░░░██║░░░╚█████╔╝╚█���███╔╝███████╗
╚═╝░░░░░╚═╝░╚═════╝░╚══════╝░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░░╚════╝░░╚════╝░╚══════╝


change your codepage i.e chcp 65001 >nul && type logo.txt

that didn't work, still outputs weird symbols. what does chcp do?

update: I tried for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com') do for %%H in (%%G) do set /A "CodePage=%%H" 2>nul %SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >nul type logo.txt %SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com %CodePage% >nul, it kind of works...
it outputs what i want but with weird �

Your updated output looks like a wrong encoding of your logo.txt file. Make sure to save it as plain ANSI (not UTFxxx)

Perhaps you could be interested in this answer
